# Code for deleting XML node

Tags: xml, vb.net, treeview

I have this XML which retains the name of some nodes in a TreeView.
After I delete the node in TreeView, I have to delete also the node from XML file.
I managed to run a code to delete the content of node Profile 2  but I want to delete also the parent node: "`<Profile></Profile>`".

Help me please with the correct code!

**These are the original nodes:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Profiles>
  <Profile>
    <Profile_Name>Profile 1</Profile_Name>
    <Profile_Path>X:\Tests</Profile_Path>
  </Profile>
  <Profile>
    <Profile_Name>Profile 2</Profile_Name>
    <Profile_Path>X:\Tests</Profile_Path>
  </Profile>
</Profiles>
```

**After running the code, results:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Profiles>
  <Profile>
    <Profile_Name>Prof 1</Profile_Name>
    <Profile_Path>X:\Tests</Profile_Path>
  </Profile>
  <Profile>
  </Profile>
</Profiles>
```

**And this is the code used:**

```
Public Sub DeleteXml()
    ProfileList.Load(xml_path)
    Dim nodes_list As XmlNodeList = ProfileList.SelectNodes("Profiles")
    Dim profile_node As XmlNode = ProfileList.SelectSingleNode("Profile")
    Dim profile_name_node As XmlNode = ProfileList.SelectSingleNode("Profile_Name")
    Dim bool As Boolean

For Each profile_node In nodes_list
            For Each profile_name_node In profile_node
                If EManager.TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text = profile_name_node.FirstChild.InnerText Then
                    bool = True                    
                Else
                    bool = False
                End If
                If bool = True Then
                    profile_name_node.RemoveAll()
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the most elegant code, but I just tested it and it works:

```
Public Sub DeleteXml()
    Dim profileList As New XmlDocument()
    profileList.Load("XmlFile1.xml")
    Dim profilesNode As XmlNode = profileList.SelectSingleNode("Profiles")
    Dim profiles As XmlNodeList = profilesNode.SelectNodes("Profile")
    For index As Integer = 0 To profiles.Count - 1
        Dim profile As XmlNode = profiles(index)
        If "Profile 2" = profile.FirstChild.InnerText Then
            profile.ParentNode.RemoveChild(profile)  
        End If
    Next
    profileList.Save("XmlFile2.xml")
End Sub
```